# cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'tx:annotation- driven'

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

My mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:::

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"  
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/database.properties" />
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.suva.*" />
         <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>  

        <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix">
                <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
            </property>
            <property name="suffix">
                <value>.jsp</value>
            </property>
        </bean>



     <bean id="dataSource"  
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
      <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />  
      <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />  
      <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />  
      <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />  
     </bean>  



     <bean id="sessionFactory"  
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">  
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />  
      <property name="hibernateProperties">  
       <props>  
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>  
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>  
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>      
       </props>  
      </property>  
     </bean>  

    </beans>
```

I am doing a spring-security application where i have to add DB validation with spring-security framework.
I have included proper jar in the class path but i am facing this compilation error.. Please point me out where i am wrong..

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using??

Comment: i am using spring-3.0 jars..

Comment: The compilation error is in the line ::
 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>  

Dont why this is happening.. i have spring-tx-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar in the class path

Comment: You have only one Spring jar version in classpath?

Comment: Also, where is the definition of `hibernateTransactionManager`? Do you have other xml config files?

Comment: i have all relevant jars for this in the classpath..and i have two other xml files in my project..@AndreiStefan

Comment: actually i am learning this and i am following a tutorial on http://www.dineshonjava.com.. can you please help me to solve this error..

Comment: Its seems like version mismatch thing to me, I faced it recently, what I did is remove the -3.0.xsd instead try .xsd with name, I guess spring will automatically pick up the latest available xsd. And ensure that you have all required jars in place.

Comment: thanks @pathfinder:: yes that is the issue i think,, actually i replaced it with other xsd and it is working now. But i am facing other problems now..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
```

I have changed my xsd to this xsd definitions and it is working  now.. As like Pathfinder2104 is saying, spring automatically takes the most recent available xsd. so better not to mention the version of the xsd.

Answer (score -1):

You just want to add following line of codes.

```
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
```

And,

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: Question is for 'tx:annotation- driven' and not 'mvc:annotation-driven'